# How to add a plugin to eclipse via cookbook using chef-solo

Tags: eclipse, plugins, pydev, chef-solo, cookbook

I have chef-solo installed on ubuntu(12.04). I have been able to successfully install eclipse using the cookbook provided in the following site: https://github.com/geocent-cookbooks/eclipse.

Now i wish to add the ***pydev plugin*** to this using chef-solo. Can someone help me on how i can do this. Do i need a new cookbook (if yes then where can i find the cookbook) or is some editing required in the existing eclipse cookbook(if yes then what is it)?

I am new to chef. Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

cookbook delivers a method to install the eclipse plugins.

default ['Eclipse'] ['plugins'] - list of repositories and install plugins to Automatically With This eclipse deployment

for pydev:

```
"default_attributes": {
   "eclipse": {
     "plugins": [{"http://pydev.org/updates" => "org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group"}]
     }
   }
}
```

check this issues (certificate error)

http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/1244/

I guess installing the certificate should work correctly.

> http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html#pydev-certificate

you would have to adapt this code to automatically add the certificate.

> https://gist.github.com/lusis/2203083

Another option is to adapt the cookbook for install liclipse (eclipse + PyDev)

> http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/

Sorry for my English.

Best regards

Comment: I added the code provided in your solution in my cookbook and ran it using chef(got no errors with respect to license), instead it gave me the following error **error: Chef::Exceptions::ContentLengthMismatch** . In order to fix this error i followed the explanation given in the following site [link] (https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5041), and set `"no_lazy_load true"` in my client.rb config. Doing this removed the error. Eclipse starts smoothly but the pydev plugin is not installed. :( what could be the problem. Could you please suggest.

Comment: I would like to add. In eclipse UI when i look under Help>>About Eclipse>>Installation Details , i can see that pydev plugin is installed version(3.5). I am guessing maybe there is some problem with this version. Is there anyway i can mention a lower version within the cookbook?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the eclipse cookbook in a vm with ubuntu 12.04 and install pydev without problems, attached to the chef-solo json file.

```
{
  "java": {
    "jdk_version": "7"
  },
  "eclipse": {
    "plugins": [ {"http://pydev.org/updates": "org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group"} ]
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[eclipse::default]"
  ]
}
```

If it does not work, attached the json file and debug log of chef run

Best Regards